# Suggestions for a command prompt permission error?

Tags: command-prompt

Whenever I try to run command prompt it comes up with this error message:

The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.

Press any key to continue. . .

I have tried running command prompt in PowerShell, batch files, as  and even java files but none of them work. I also tried to run it as an admin but it still displays this error. Does anyone have any suggestions or tutorials to fixing this problem?

Comment: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/disablecmd.htm - If this is a GPO in a corp environment you would need to talk to the admin.

Comment: I tried logging on as an admin and it gives me the same error. I also can't open registry or task manager :(

Comment: You could ask over on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but they will probably tell you that the PC is likely infected with malware and you should google for solutions.

Comment: I asked on Super User but then they redirected me here to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a school issued computer? If you are then the master admin probably disabled it for all users and admins because of the ability of abuse with command prompt. If you can also assess powershell you might want to report that to the school admins. If you are on your personal computer like Andrew said you might want to run a virus scan. At my school if you went to the System32 folder to assess command prompt that way it should work normally and allow you to insert commands. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I am on a school issued computer and I am able to assess command prompt via the System32 folder.